# Class number and complex conjugation

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $h$ be the be the class number of the ring of integers of the $p$th cyclotomic field. Suppose $p\mid h$ and let $I$ be an ideal of order $m$ such that $p \mid m$. Does $p$ divide the order of $I \cdot \bar I$, where $\bar{I}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ denote the $p$-Sylow subgroup of $K = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p)$. The group $C$ has an action of complex conjugation. If $p \ne 2$, one can write

$$C = C^{+} \oplus C^{-},$$

where $C^{+}$ is the part fixed by complex conjugation, and $C^{-}$ the part where complex conjugation acts by $-1$. Given an ideal $I$, one can write the class of $I$ in $\mathrm{Cl}(K)$ as an element of $C$ plus an element of order prime to $p$. Then $J = I \cdot \overline{I}$ will have order divisible by $p$ if and only if the part of $I$ in $C$ does not lie completely in $C^{-}$.

Now one has the following facts:

1. The power of $p$ dividing the order of $C$ is the power of $p$ dividing $h$. (This is clear).
2. The power of $p$ dividing the order of $C^{+}$ is the power of $p$ dividing $h^{+}$, the class group of $K^{+} = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta^{-1}_p)$.

As you can see, if $C^{+}$ is trivial, then $J$ has order prime to $p$. Experimetally, $C^{+}$ is often trivial even when $C^{-}$ is non-trivial.
Vandiver's conjecture implies that $h^{+}$ is prime to $p$, for example,
although nobody really believes Vandivier's conjecture. However, this shows that if Vandivier's conjecture is true, then the answer to your question is that $J$ never has order divisible by $p$.

For example, if $p < 10^8$ and $p | h$, then $p$ does not divide $h^{+}$ (i.e. Vandivier's conjecture is known), and so the answer in this case is that $J$ has order prime to $p$.

On the other hand, if $p$ divides $h^{+}$, and $C^{+}$ is non-trivial, then the answer will be that $J$ has order divisible by $p$ if and only if the projection of $I$ to $C$ lands completely in $C^{-}$.

Some other relevant facts: The power of $p$ dividing $h^{-} = h/h^{+}$ is at least as large as the power of $p$ dividing $h^{+}$. That is, if $C^{+}$ is non-trivial, then $C^{-}$ is non-trivial. In particular, if $p$ divides $h$, then $C^{+}$ is non-trivial. Hence, if $p$ divides $h$, there will at least exist one ideal (coming from $C^{-}$ such that $I$ has order $p$ but $J$ is trivial.)